# Ubuntu/sssd/Active Directory suddenly broke

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, sssd

Windows Server 2022 domain controller, Ubuntu 22.04, sssd 2.6.3. System joined to AD via 'realm join'.

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
domains = dev.domain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh


[domain/dev.domain.com]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = DEV.DOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ad_domain = dev.domain.com
use_fully_qualified_names = False
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_tokengroups = True
```

Everything was fine since the system was set up, until the February 2024 update was installed on the DC. On some hosts, AD users are unable to log on, either locally or over SSH, receiving an 'access denied' message.

The changes were backed out by reverting the DC from checkpoint, but this did not resolve the issue.

The only thing I can see in the logs that looks out of place is this, in /var/log/sssd/sssd_pam.log:

[pam] [cache_req_common_process_dp_reply] (0x0040): [CID#2] CR #3: Could not get account info [14]: Bad address

Adding debug_level = 9 to sssd.conf did not produce anything useful either.

However, running 'id username' as root for any AD user succeeds and returns their uid and gids, successfully resolving group names.

Leaving the domain, deleting the computer account and rejoining creates a new computer account, but does not resolve the issue.

Not sure where to even look for more info...

Edit: found another oddity... sssctl domain-list times out without any output. Adding 'ad_server = dc1.dev.domain.com' to sssd.conf fixes that, which is suggestive of a DNS issue, but DNS looks totally fine, and lookups work. sssctl domain-status dev.domain.com returns this:

```
Online status: Online

Active servers:
AD Global Catalog: not connected
AD Domain Controller: dc1.dev.domain.com

Discovered AD Global Catalog servers:
- dc1.dev.domain.com

Discovered AD Domain Controller servers:
- dc1.dev.domain.com
```

Comment: Have you clear the `sssd` cache?

Comment: Yes, both via sss_cache -E and rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*

Comment: `Not sure where to even look` the output states that you aren't connected to a GC. Run this from a Windows endpoint that is not the DC: `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com`

Comment: Seems fine:

`C:\Windows\system32>nltest /dsgetdc:dev.domain.com
           DC: \\DC1.dev.domain.com
      Address: \\192.168.195.151
     Dom Guid: 44bc40db-51d6-41a8-8b73-e0dc0ad69eac
     Dom Name: dev.domain.com
  Forest Name: dev.domain.com
 Dc Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
Our Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
        Flags: PDC GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV GTIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE FULL_SECRET WS DS_8 DS_9 DS_10 KEYLIST
The command completed successfully`

Comment: Okay, I don't know what it was, but now it's working. I did an `apt purge realmd sssd sssd-tools libnss-sss libpam-sss adcli samba-common-bin`, deleted /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and /var/lib/sss, then reinstalled the same packages, rejoined the domain and AD users were able to log on like nothing happened.